# How to hide Intellij file size/modification times in Project Explorer

Tags: intellij-idea

For some reason my Intellij started showing file size and timestamps in the Project Explorer. May be I did something without knowing. It is noise most of the time.

How do I hide this info?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this by unchecking the following menu item: `View | Appearance | Details in Tree View`.